# Android: How to retrieve the Default NFC-method

Tags: android, settings, nfc, android-settings

I have an Android app that uses NFC and I wonder if there's a way to programmatically retrieve (and possibly change) the `Default NFC method`?

[image: Default NFC method setting]

I also noticed that not every device has these settings, so I wonder if it's a specific Samsung setting? The best thing I can come up with is to navigate to the NFC-settings using `ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS`.